# Verilog Matrix multiplication error in synthesis

Tags: verilog, xilinx, hdl

I am writing a 32row by 32col multiplication on Verilog. I have tried to synthesize the code but it gives an error saying the signal is connected to multiple drivers. The code below is uncomplete but gives the same error. I am new to Verilog and I don't get know how to fix this. Could you give suggestions on how to fix this. I am using Xillinx version 14.5 and the FPGA is virtex 5.

I am using inbuilt multipliers and inbuilt adders.
Here is the code:

```
module matrixMult(Arow, Bcol,CLK, AxB);
    input [1023:0] Arow;
    input [1023:0] Bcol;
    input          CLK;
    output [31:0] AxB;

     wire [1023:0] Arow;
     wire [1023:0] Bcol;
     wire [1024:0] ab;
     wire [1024:0] AxB;


     // multiplication
     ip32Mult a1b1(CLK, ab[1023:992], Arow[1023:992],Bcol[1023:992]);
     ip32Mult a2b2(CLK, ab[991:960], Arow[991:960],Bcol[992:960]);

     // addition // no clock enable
     ip32Add ab1( AxB[31:0], ab[1023:992], ab[991:960]);

endmodule
```

The Error:

```
ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <matrixMult> on signal <ab<992>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.
```

Additional information:
How the ip32Add looks like

```
module ip32Add (
  clk, s, a, b
)/* synthesis syn_black_box syn_noprune=1 */;
  input clk;
  output [31 : 0] s;
  input [31 : 0] a;
  input [31 : 0] b;
  ....
```

How the ip32Mult looks like:

```
module ip32Mult (
  clk, p, a, b
)/* synthesis syn_black_box syn_noprune=1 */;
  input clk;
  output [31 : 0] p;
  input [31 : 0] a;
  input [31 : 0] b;
  ...
```

Comment: I used the inbuilt ip multipliers. Should I paste the whole code here. It's quite long.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *ip32Add* header has a `clk` pin but the *ab1* instance does not. Therefore with connect by order, `AxB[31:0]` is connected to the `clk` and `ab[1023:992]` is connected to the output `s`. `ab[1023:992]` also connected to the output `p` if instance *a1b1*. Thereby  `ab[1023:992]` having two drivers. There are probably warnings for instance *ab1* such as width mismatch and `b` not being connected.

I'd recommend connecting your ports by name (eg: `.portname(netname)`) instead of by order. Order does not matter with connect by name and is more explicit. If clock doesn't matter but the pin does exists, *ab1* should look something like this:

```
ip32Add ab1( .s(AxB[31:0]), .a(ab[1023:992]), .b(ab[991:960]), .clk() );
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit too long for a comment but not to be considered a full answer. 
Could you redefine you module using the modern style:

```
module matrixMult(
  input [1023:0] Arow,
  input [1023:0] Bcol,
  input          CLK,
  output [31:0]  AxB );


 wire [1024:0] ab;
```

You had this line :

```
 wire AxB;
```

Which not sure if it would cause it to be 1 bit or if the preceding statement (32bits wide) would win.

It would be helpful if the question could also show headers for :

```
ip32Mult
ip32Add
```

As the error suggest the ab connection might be connected to two drivers rather than an input and an output.